# Errors running django tests after python 2/3 upgrade, unittest.loader._FailedTest

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm helping my group upgrade their application from python 2 to 3, and am running into errors with the unit tests. When I run the tests with:

```
python3 manage.py test groupapp --settings=settings.deploy_dev
```

I get the errors below. But if I run with:

```
python3 manage.py test groupapp.tests --settings=settings.deploy_dev
```

the errors do not occur. Its worth noting that these errors occur even after I deleted all our tests from the tests folder, and as far as I can tell they aren't connected to an actual test case.

I don't understand the difference between these two calls in python 3. In python 2 if I run the two calls I get the same result (no test failures).

````
groupapp_v2.groupapp.admin (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR
groupapp_v2.groupapp.models (unittest.loader._FailedTest) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: groupapp_v2.groupapp.admin (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: groupapp_v2.groupapp.admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 462, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/matthew/bitbucket/consortium-website/groupapp_v2/groupapp/admin/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Grid, GridAdmin)
  File "/Users/matthew/virtualenv/groupapp-python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 110, in register
    raise AlreadyRegistered('The model %s is already registered' % model.__name__)
django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model Grid is already registered


======================================================================
ERROR: groupapp_v2.groupapp.models (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: groupapp_v2.groupapp.models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 462, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/matthew/bitbucket/consortium-website/groupapp_v2/groupapp/models/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .deployable import *
  File "/Users/matthew/bitbucket/consortium-website/groupapp_v2/groupapp/models/deployable.py", line 22, in <module>
    class Keyword_LibraryM2M(Model):
  File "/Users/matthew/virtualenv/groupapp-python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 118, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class groupapp_v2.groupapp.models.deployable.Keyword_LibraryM2M doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test discovery in unittest (the default Django test runner) changes a lot from 2.7 to 3. What you're trying to do is in fact two different ways for calling test, from the Django documentation:

> ```
> # Run all the tests in the animals.tests module
> $ ./manage.py test animals.tests
>
> # Run all the tests found within the 'animals' package
> $ ./manage.py test animals
> ```

it is possible that your app has more tests discovered that the ones you're explicitly telling the runner to run, it's not a problem with your app, it's just how libraries are.

Comment: Thanks! I was having a hard time finding info on these changes.