# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.config' when running test in Django 4.1

Tags: django

I have a django (v4.1) project with no tests defined. Before I started writing tests, I ran `python manage.py test`, expecting to get something like:

```
Found 0 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

But instead I got this:

```
Found 1 test(s).
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: django.config (unittest.loader._FailedTest.django.config)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: django.config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 440, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 350, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.config'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58513628/10588618) but it seems more to do with a migration problem from Django 2 to 3 and how to run tests.

**Clarifications**:

1. When I say there are no tests defined, I mean that there are the auto-generated `test.py` files created by `manage.py startapp` in three applications, but I've commented out the standard import statement `# from django.test import TestCase`.
2. I tried searching for any instances of `django.config` using  `grep -r "django.config" .` from the repo directory (which is above django's `BASE_DIRECTORY` and there are no instances of that in any of the files.
3. I have named the "project" directory (the one containing `settings`) "`config`" so wondered if there was come import confusion stemming from that. Did a search for all occurrences of "config":

```
$ grep -r "config" .
./templates/base.html:    using the 'builtins' key of OPTIONS in settings (in ./config/base/templates.py).
./config/admin.py:    default_site = 'config.admin.CustomAdminSite'
./config/asgi.py:ASGI config for server project.
./config/settings/base/databases.py:from config.utilities import dprint
./config/settings/base/databases.py:        "NAME": str(BASE_DIR / "config/db.sqlite3"),
./config/settings/base/core.py:ROOT_URLCONF = "config.urls"
./config/settings/base/core.py:WSGI_APPLICATION = "config.wsgi.application"
./config/settings/base/authentication.py:# authall configuration settings
./config/settings/base/applications.py:    # NB see ./authentication.py for social account config of allauth
./config/settings/base/applications.py:    "config.admin.CustomAdminConfig", # replaces django.contrib.admin
./config/settings/__init__.py:from config.utilities import dprint
./config/settings/__init__.py:SECRETS_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'config/secrets/'
./config/wsgi.py:WSGI config for server project.
./apps/accounts/admin.py:from config.utilities import dprint
./apps/core/views.py:from config.utilities import dprint
./manage.py:    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings")
```

Project structure beneath django's `BASE_DIRECTORY`:

```
├── __init__.py
├── apps
│   ├── accounts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── managers.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── signals.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── recipes
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── tests.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── views.py
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── secrets
│   │   ├── development.secret
│   │   └── secret.template
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── base
│   │   └── development
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utilities.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── styles.css
│   └── js
└── templates
    ├── allauth
    │   └── account
    ├── base.html
    ├── base_with_nav.html
    ├── core
    │   ├── index.html
    │   └── item1.html
    ├── navbar.html
    └── navbar_rhs_items.html
```

Comment: Do you have a local file of your own named `django.py`?

Comment: No there's no file named `django.py`

Comment: Hmm.  Did you name the project itself django?

Comment: Yup. I named the BASE_DIRECTORY as django. I'll change it when I get back to my computer and let you know. Won't be doing that again :(

Comment: @JohnGordon - I confirm that was the problem. If you could write your comment as an Answer I'll accept it. Thanks for spotting this so quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that -- as pointed out by [John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) -- I had named the BASE_DIRECTORY `django`. Renaming it (I suspect to anything else, but in my case I used `src`) solved the problem.

John if you want to provide an answer for this I'll mark yours as the accepted answer. Just closing off the question with this one.